# Is this the right way to handle errors using the fetch api?

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, web-development

I am using the fetch api in my handleSubmit function in a React component to post data like this:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var error = false;

var { username, password } = this.state

var mailFormat = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/


if (!username.match(mailFormat)) {
  this.setState({ usernameError: true });
  error = true;
} else {
  this.setState({ usernameError: false });
}

if (password.length < 8) {
  this.setState({ passwordError: true });
  error = true;
} else {
  this.setState({ passwordError: false })
}

if (error) {
  this.setState({ formSuccess: false });
  return;
}

return window.fetch('http://localhost:8016/users/registration', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ username_email: username, password: password })
})
 // .then(this.handleErrors)
 .then((response)=>{
  if (response.ok) {
   const { token } = response.clone();

   const loginOptions = {
    token,
    cookieOptions: { expires: 1 },
    callback: () => Router.push('/login')
   }
   setTimeout(() => {
    login(loginOptions)
   }, 5000)

   this.setState({
    username: '', password: '', userNameDup: false, formError: false, formSuccess: true
   })

   return response.json();
  } else if (!response.ok) {
   if (response.status === 409) {
    console.log("response.status ", response.status);
    this.setState({
     userNameDup: true, formError: true, formSuccess: false
    });
    return;
   }
  }
  return response;
 })
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

My question regarding using fetch is typically one codes it like this to make a post request.

```
var url = 'https://example.com/profile';
var data = {username: 'example'};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

As you can see in my version I have a conditional handling the error. (I’m pretty sure I’ve seen a version using a try catch block. I guess I’m used to the error/node style of handling errors.)

Anyway, I guess I’m wondering what would be the point of the catch function if the else clause in my conditional is handling the error? Will that still be utilized I mean?

So Can anyone show me what is the most ubiquitous style to handle the situation regarding error handling?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status
>   even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve
>   normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on
>   network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

Knowing that, then you should at least check if `response.ok == true` before proceeding. The example you gave assumes it will always go the happy path which obviously is not the correct way to handle the response.

What you have in your code is ideal.

P.S. you can simplify `else if (!response.ok)` to just `else`